# Running Shell Script from Applescript

Tags: python, bash, macos, shell

I want to run a Shell script using Automator in OSX. The shell script calls a Python file which is located in the folder "/Users/Tex/Python". My code is:

```
on run {input, parameters}

tell application "Terminal"
    do shell script "/Users/Tex/anaconda3/bin/python  /users/Tex/Python/MoveFiles.py $@"
end tell

return input
```

When I execute the automator script I get an error as follows:

```
Terminal got an error: /users/Tex/anaconda3/bin/python:
can't open file '/users/Tex//Python/Move_Files.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I suspect that the problem is that the "/Users/Tex" folder is located on a different drive to the OSX operating system but that the Shell interpreter is not aware of this. I have tried using the full path to the python file, i.e. including the volume name (iMac Disk A) however the fact that this has spaces in it seems to create yet another issue for the Shell.

Appreciate feedback on how to make thsi work!

Comment: I see *two* differences between the file you say you open, and the path in the error message. Which is it? Anything else you got wrong?

Comment: On Unix, volumes are irrelevant when interpreting a path. If an absolute path is valid from the command line, it should be ok here.

Comment: Alexis: Yes, I edited the paths and filenames to make them less lengthy. The filename is incorrect on the "Do Shell" line, it should read "Move_files.py". I'm afraid that I don't see a second error between the input and error output. Unfortunately I also don't get the gist of your second comment regarding paths. Can you please explain a little more. Thanks!

Comment: Unix is not Windows. An absolute path starts at the root, and transparently descends into drives when it comes to their mount point. Find out the correct path to use by opening Terminal, going to the folder containing your script, and typing `pwd`. Python is clearly telling you that the path you gave it does not exist. Since you faked the paths in the question, there's no more to say really.

Comment: With due respect I think that you are missing the point of my post. Firstly I am using osx, not Windows. Secondly, I understand the concept of the absolute path. What I do't understand is why Shell does not take account of the 'alias' that I think is inherently in place as a result of specifying that my home directory (/Users/Tex) resides on a different disk form the boot drive.

Comment: OS X is Unix. The right term for what you call an "alias" is a mount point, and they are completely transparent in Unix (including OS X) unless you specifically go checking at every step, as a very few utilities allow you to do. In other words, Python (the error is not from the shell) does treat the mount point as a subdirectory. The problem is not where you think it is.

Comment: Unless you have added an actual OS X alias (not a symlink) to the second drive, in which case you should use Terminal as I suggested to find out the correct path.